# Spring Boot App with Maven and Wildly (26.1.1) - PAGE NOT FOUND Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, wildfly

I have created a Spring Boot application. I use WildFly as the application server - this is what I want to use to run the application.

These are the Java and Maven related files I have:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @Autowired
  private Student student;

  @GetMapping(value="/index")
  public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

Of course I have the main method with the Spring Boot related annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTestApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

I have the Maven file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.globalsoftwaresupport</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-boot-test</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <deploy.jboss.host>127.0.0.1</deploy.jboss.host>
    <deploy.jboss.port>9990</deploy.jboss.port>
    <deploy.jboss.username>balazs</deploy.jboss.username>
    <deploy.jboss.password>balazs1990</deploy.jboss.password>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                <hostname>${deploy.jboss.host}</hostname>
                <port>${deploy.jboss.port}</port>
                <username>${deploy.jboss.username}</username>
                <password>${deploy.jboss.password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

When I build the project with **mvn clean install** then Maven compiles and deployed the app to the Wildfly server.

[image]

So far so good I have the application on the server. First of all:

1.) is it not a problem that I have the SNAPSHOT present in the context root?

2.) another problem is that I can not run the application - I start WildFly server in Eclipse and I check the context root.

[image]

Can you help me why is this happening? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Springboot is meant to be a standalone server - it includes a server inside of it.  Why do you want to use it in another server?

Comment: I want to use it with JPA and Hibernate. So I guess the embedded Tomcat server is not an option

Comment: Springboot has [support for JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).  If you go the Wildfly only route then you have it too.  It's just trying to use spring **boot** with Wildfly.  Really if you're using Wildfly I'd argue you don't need spring but it's got a long legacy of code so it's common.